# Operational Amplifier is not working

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm trying to use a operational amplifier ([INA2126](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ina2126.pdf)), so I put 10V in vcc, -10V in vss, 0V in reference. The sense pin is connected to the output pin. But the output voltage is always 9.56V, even when the positive and negative input voltage are 0V. I'm using 4kohms resistors, but the output is the same if the resistor pins are not connected. May anyone help me please?
Here's a schematic for better visualization. 4k resistors generate a gain of 25V / V
[image]

Comment: "INA" means that it's an instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: A schematic of your setup would be appreciated.

Comment: Way too much incomprehensible handwaving.  Show a schematic.  And -1 since that should have been obvious.

Comment: @ThePhoton I removed my wrong comment.

Comment: I apologize for the failings and I thank comments and contributions

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, Ignacio. I thought instrumental amplifiers were kind of op-amp

Comment: You can build an instrumentation amplifier out of op amps, but they are different.  In particular, an (ideal) op amp has infinite gain.

Answer (score 1):

An instrumentation amp, such as the INA2126 that you are using, is not really a type of op-amp. Unlike an op-amp, instrumentation amps have a specified gain (usually set by an external resistor), and are therefore used without feedback.

Op-amps are similar in that they are differential amplifiers with single-ended outputs, but the defining characteristic of an op-amp is an extremely large gain, which cannot be set precisely. Op-amps are therefore usually used with feedback, in circuits where their gain is assumed to be infinite.

Your schematic seems to be correct, which suggests a wiring fault (could the output be tied to V- elsewhere in the circuit?), or possibly a faulty chip.

Comment: Instrumentation amplifiers are never used with feedback. Feedback would make it something other than an instrumentation amplifier.

Comment: There is no connection between V- and the output, or between V+ and output. I'm sure. I've tested other INA2126, but the result is the same.

Comment: @AlexdeSousa Can you take a photograph of your circuit while measuring the fault, and upload it?

Comment: Your schematic looks fine; almost certainly there is a wiring error.  Do channels A and B both behave the same?  Measure some voltages. Do you read 10V on V+, -10V on V- and 0V at REF_A and REF_B?  It is important that you measure directly at the pins of the chip itself.

Comment: Channels A and B behave the same. I measure directly on the pins, which were really 10, -10 and 0 volts, respectively. Soon I will post a photo of the circuit.

Comment: Ok, next connect V_INA+ and V_INA- both to zero volts.  Pins 1 and 2 should measure 0V, and pins 3, 4, 6 and 7 should also measure 0V.